# How to Install Skype on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: dpkg, skype, 32-bit

I've been struggling to install Skype on my newly setup Ubuntu 18.04

I've tried several tutorials and executed below commands but none of them worked for me.

```
wget https://repo.skype.com/latest/skypeforlinux-64.deb
```

Above downloaded but when I tried to install it never start installation process.
Than I step up to alternative method that is as below.

```
sudo dpkg -i skypeforlinux-64.deb
```

When I execute above command it give me error

```
zerocool@ZeroCool:~$ sudo dpkg -i skypeforlinux-64.deb dpkg: error
processing archive skypeforlinux-64.deb (--install):  package architecture (amd64) does not match system (i386) 
Errors were encountered while processing:  skypeforlinux-64.deb
```

Note : I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 on 32 bit system powered by Intel I3.

Please guide me I'm new on Ubuntu and want to learn it.

Comment: What do you mean by flavor ? How can I check that ? Sorry to trouble you but As I said I'm new on ubuntu.

Comment: I could be mistaken but isn't there an official Skype download in the "Ubuntu Software" app?

Comment: @creativiii, Exactly But I forgot to mention that when I search for skype in software center I cant find skype over there that's why I am installing via termianal.

Comment: @Kulfy, I didnt get what You said but I've installed ubuntu 16.04 and than updated it to 18.04

Comment: @Kulfy, Its not duplicate since I'm on 18.04 and If you have idea how can i upgrade to 64bit from 32 bit provide some best reference. If you have time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87155/discussion-between-web-developer-and-kulfy).